# Synchronizing numeric user id's between Dockerfiles and docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, rancher

I have a docker-compose newbie question. We have an existing Jenkins build that creates Docker images and pushes them to an in house Artifactory repository. This is driven by using Maven/Docker and two Dockerfiles, one for the app and one for a volume/data container. The Dockerfiles look something like this:

App:

```
FROM centos
RUN useradd -u 6666 -ms /bin/bash foouser
COPY src/main/resources/home/foouser/.bashrc /home/foouser/
RUN chown -R foouser:foouser /home/foouser
USER foouser
COPY src/main/resources/opt/myapp/bin/startup.sh /opt/myapp/bin/
WORKDIR /home/foouser
ENTRYPOINT /opt/myapp/bin/startup.sh && /bin/bash
```

Data container:

```
FROM centos
# Environment variable for the path to mount/create. Defaults to /opt/data
ENV DATA_VOL_PATH="/opt/data"

# Make sure the user id is the same as the container using the volume, otherwise we may run into permission issues on
# the container mounting the volume.
RUN useradd -u 6666 -ms /bin/bash foouser && \
    mkdir -p "$DATA_VOL_PATH" && \
    chown -R foouser:foouser "$DATA_VOL_PATH"
VOLUME [ "$DATA_VOL_PATH" ]
```

I omitted stuff like labels, etc for brevity. So the images produced by the build from these Dockerfiles will end up in the local Artifactory repo. We're using Rancher/Cattle to instantiate these images, and I've added the Artifactory repo to Rancher so it can pull from there. The docker-compose.yml file in Rancher looks something like this:

```
# The data/volumes container for the data.
data:
  image: data-image

# App
myapp:
  image: app-image
environment:
  DATA_VOL_PATH:
volumes_from:
  - data
```

I know that I can pass environment variables from docker-compose (as in the DATA_VOL_PATH above), but I'm confused as to how things work. My understanding is that the commands in the Dockerfile are executed when I run docker build, and after that, the image is immutable. When I instantiate a container based on the image, it creates a new writable UFS layer on top of it if I've understood things correctly. So in the case of the data container, I can't really change the volume once it's created, right? If that assumption is correct, it boils down to 1) how do I best synchronize user ids across two different system (Maven for creating the Docker images, and Rancher for instantiating container clusters), and 2) is it better to drive the creation of the data volume container entirely from docker-compose.yml? How would I then be able to replicate the data container's Dockerfile content in docker-compose.yml?

I assume this is a fairly common scenario, so there must be a few "best practices" solutions out there. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is confusing. The volumes will be created by the containers (not by compose) and you can `chown` them to the user you want. As you have the same user in both containers there should be no issues for IO between them. For anything on the host system the question is why do you need anything on the host system? You could have a container running under the same UID creating docker images for you. But in any case, you can have the same UID created on the host system. The difficulty only comes into play if you are using somebody else's containers where you do not control UIDs.

Comment: Oleg, I'm slightly confused about the correlation between the use of Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml, so that may be why the question itself is confusing. Maybe I should rephrase the question and start from the other end. I've also been told that named volumes seem to be the preferred way to do this. I'm still confused, but in a slightly more enlightened way :-)

Comment: You are not getting answers, which, most likely, means people do not understand what you are asking. I would suggest that you learn iteratively: go away from your Jenkins build and read first a couple of tutorials on docker.com, then create a couple of containers of your own and link them together with compose. At that moment you will be understanding the basics and you will be able to comprehend the setup you have for Jenkins. If at that moment you will still have open issues, ask one most important question at a time without too many details of your custom Jenkins/maven/whatever setup.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue as well: in my case there was a non-root process inside Docker container, and this process needed to access files mounted from host, so I had to pay attention to `UID`/`GID` values both inside Docker image and host.

I'm afraid that there is no good decision for it. Docker images are really immutable, so you'll have to establish some agreements or use third-party software to control both build and deployment process.

I would also strongly encourage you to stop using `docker-compose` and to give a try to `SaltStack`.

Comment: How exactly a switch to SaltStack would be beneficial for this fairly simply exercise controlled by one simple compose file? Cost of time to learn and setup vs the productivity, clarity or simplicity gain please.

Comment: Someone at work pointed me to this conversation. I guess essentially named volumes is the way to go:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/17798